# Unable to run Flutter Project with Package

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I created a new app.

Added audioplayers flutter package from https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers.

Shows an error from Android Embedding. I followed the instructions https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration.

Now I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':audioplayers'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':audioplayers'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Then I followed https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1407 thread to do what suggested.
Now I'm getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\build.gradle' line: 49

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':audioplayers'.



Could not get unknown property 'kotlin_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm very new in android studio development, it drives me crazy with these configurations. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post your yaml file and flutter doctor result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who came up with the same problem I have. The project I'm working came from Git and I think that project wasn't updated for Android Embedding v2 so I got the first error.

Now in the second error, all I did was to read other's bug fixes (not officially).

1. Adding the dependencies and kotlin-version (1.4.20) needed for the main package(audioplayers). C:\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.17.1\android\ 
   [image]
2. Making the android project's app build.gradle>defaultConfig>minSdkVersion to 23 (from 16)
   [image]
3. Use pub get and update in pubspec.yaml.